# TexSubImage2D produces a garbled texture for specific images only

Tags: c++, opengl, glteximage2d

I'm trying to get a texture to be rendered on top of another one, like in the image below:

[image: Desired]

However, only that image gets rendered properly. My other images get garbled and "twisted". If you look carefully, it's as if the rows were shifted:

[image: Actual]

In the above example, I used the very same cat picture in the background. Both this cat picture, and all other images I generate end up garbled, except that one special picture, for some reason. I have looked at EXIF data, and other than the fact that it doesn't use sRGB, it is in the exact same format as the others. It has an alpha channel and everything.

I believe it has something to do with pixel alignment, given how the rows are shifted, but I have tried literally every possible combination of alignment and nothing as worked so far. Here is my code:

```
int height, width = 512;
m_pSubImage = SOIL_load_image("sample.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);

glGenTextures(1, &m_textureObj);
glBindTexture(m_textureTarget, m_textureObj);
...
glActiveTexture(TextureUnit);
glBindTexture(m_textureTarget, m_textureObj);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 20, 10, 100, 100, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pSubImage);
```

The code for loading the background image is similar, except that it uses this call instead of glTexSubImage2D:

```
glTexImage2D(m_textureTarget, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pImage);
```

Comment: Both the image that work and some that do not are in this album. Apparently I can't post over two links http://imgur.com/a/ScDF6

Comment: You called `glTexImage2D` to create the texture, before using `glTexSubImage2D` to write to it, correct?

Comment: Yes. The `glTexImage2D` call renders the cat background

Comment: Wait, when you say "one texture rendered on top of another one", do you mean you have two textures and draw a quad with each that get composed in the output?  Or you're sticking the second texture into a subsection of the first texture?  What I mean is, are `m_textureTarget` the same for both background and foreground?

Comment: Is there a `glTexImage2D` in the `...` section of code left out?

Comment: I want to alter the texture in the texture object before rendering, yes. Both have the same texture targets, `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. There is no `glTexImage2D` in the `...` section

Comment: Actually, where do the `100`, `100` in the `glTexSubImage2D` call come from?  They have to match the image you're loading into the texture.

Comment: Oh, man I feel like an idiot. I had no idea width and height had to match the size of the image being loaded! Thanks!

Comment: How else would OpenGL know the memory layout of the data your `m_pSubImage` points to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask whether `m_textureObj` was the same for both background and foregroumd.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you aren't passing the width and height correctly to `glTexSubImage2D`.  Note that you need the number of pixels stored per scanline, which is often not exactly the "logical" width of the image, but rounded up to a multiple of 4.

The difference between the "logical" and "storage" width will leave a few padding pixels left over on each scan line, which will be interpreted as the leftmost pixels of the next scanline, and accumulate as you move down the image.  That creates the slant effect you observe.

Comment: But the `glTexImage2D` call renders the texture without a problem, apparently. If that were the problem, it would have been displayed on the background as well, wouldn't it? And why is that one image not affected?

Comment: @Daniel: Just caught that typo.  I meant the subimage call.  The `glTexImage2D` call actually requires a power of two, and causes other failures if it isn't.

Comment: Might not even be a problem with padding. He just passes 100, 100 for the size to `glTexSubImage()`. I suspect that the image is not 100x100.

Comment: @Reto: Well, it's still a violation of the rule that the width parameter has to match the memory layout.

Comment: I had no idea that the width and height parameters needed to match the image being loaded on top. As a followup question, how would I go about using only a section of a texture to render on top of another? For example, having only a cat ear on the top left square?

Comment: @Daniel: You load up the whole texture, and then when you draw a textured triangle, you set the `s, t` coordinates mapping the texture onto your triangle vertices.  That's `glTexCoord` in OpenGL 1.x-2.x, and controlled by your shader that does the texture lookup in OpenGL 3+

Comment: @Daniel: Oh I think I understand your confusion.  `glTexSubImage2D` doesn't create a texture from part of an image.  It overwrites part of a texture, from the whole image.  (The texture needs to already exist)

Comment: But it's impossible to do this over a single triangle, then? I would need extra vertices in the corner of the section I want to replace to input the texture coordinates?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm still not clear whether you're trying to get all this into one texture, or into two separate textures so you can have triangles on the screen using the background texture, and other triangles using the foreground texture.  The latter method is much much easier.

Comment: I'm slowly trying to make a font engine. I Figured it would be faster to just print the glyps on top of an alpha texture instead of creating a quad for every character. Now I'm not so sure

Comment: @Daniel: What @BenVoigt suggests is probably the easiest approach for what I think you're trying to achieve. Load each texture separately, draw a quad for each, and compose as desired by the right choice of positions and texture coordinates. If you want to compose everything into one texture, but need scaling, cropping, etc, you can attach your textures to FBOs, and use `glBlitFramebuffer` to copy content from one to the other.

Comment: @Daniel: One more thing. To use only part of your data with `glTexSubImage2D`, I think you could do that by setting `glPixelStore(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, ...)`.

Comment: @Daniel: What I always did for that is to have one texture with all the glyphs tiled (use the OS's font support to generate the tiled image, either offline, or during loading)  Then render using a quad for each character of output, using `gxTexCoord` to pull the glyph out of the texture.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yea, that is what I originally thought of doing. I figured that rendering a text or a small paragraph would cause a noticeable performance hit due to so many polygons being created/destroyed. However, doing the way I tried to seems to be pretty hard. glBlitFramebuffer might work, though

Comment: @Daniel: 3D scenes use hundreds of thousands of triangles, so having one thousand quads for your text is no big deal.  You can optimize a little by using a texture with tiled decals that aren't single glyphs but entire words (if you reuse that word a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be checking for failures.  The following failure modes of `glTexSubImage2D` are especially relevant here:

> - `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if `xoffset < 0`, `xoffset + width > w`, `yoffset < 0`, `yoffset + height > h`, where  `w` is the width and `h` is the height of the texture image being modified.
> - `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if width or height is less than 0.
> - **`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if the texture array has not been defined by a previous  `glTexImage2D` or `glCopyTexImage2D` operation whose `internalformat` matches the format of `glTexSubImage2D`.**

Comment: While testing for errors is always a good idea, I don't think this is the problem the poster is having. He's trying to replace part of an already existing texture (the cat image) with new data (the checkerboard). So in this case, `glTexImage2D` was called before, and the formats match.

Comment: @Reto: A comment beneath the question said there's no `glTexImage2D` between the call to `glGenTextures` and the call to `glTexSubImage2D`.

Comment: Hmm, yes. There's some contradictory information in this whole thread. I don't think he would get the result he's getting if there was no `glTexImage2D` call for this texture anywhere. Would be useful to see more code to be completely sure what's going on.